# _lte, __name, __startswith etc. queries in django - where are documented?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I don't know if I am blind or something, I am checking django documentation, query sets and I see practice of using __let, __name etc, but I don't see where this terms are defined? Can you help me with this?

I am checking all this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `Field Lookups`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups

BasicComparisonFilters as __gte, __lte are documented here:
https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/BasicComparisonFilters

Comment: Ha no worries, lots of documentation so it's easy to miss - hope it helped

Comment: At the Django site it now says (alarmingly!) that 1.10 is an "insecure" version. It's certainly not the latest: docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups

Answer (score 2):

It is located in the QuerySet documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/